# Music Player Program...Help calculating length

Tags: java

I'm creating a program for an assignment that is meant to display the Title, Artist, and song length of a user's selected song. I can display the artist and song without too much of an issue, but I'm having trouble calculating the song's length, a song of 157 secs should be listed as 2:37. The only direction I have for this is:

A constructor that takes four arguments: the title, the artist, and two arguments representing the song length in minutes and seconds. Use the formula ℎ=×60+ to convert the last two arguments to get the length of the song in seconds.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

```
//Class file


public class Song
{ 
    // instance variable declaration 
   private String songTitle;
   private String songArtist;
   private int songLength;
   
   //default constructor 
   public Song()
   {
   this.songTitle= "Untitled";
   this.songArtist="Unknown";
   this.songLength =0;
   }
   //
   public Song (String title,String artist,int min, int sec )
   {
       this.songTitle = title; 
       this.songArtist = artist;
       this.songLength=(min*60)+sec;
   }
   
   //Assessor and mutator methods 
   public String getTitle()
   {
   return songTitle;
   }
   
   public String getArtist()
   {
   return songArtist;
   }
   
   public int getLength()
   {
   return songLength;
   }
   
   public void setTitle (String title){
    this.songTitle= title; 
   }
   
   public void setArtist (String artist){
   this.songArtist=artist;
   }
   
   public void setLength(int length){
   this.songLength=length;
   
   }
  
// prints Output
   public void display( ){
  
   System.out.println(getTitle()+" "+ getArtist()+"-"+ getLength());
   
   }
   }

//Main method

public class assignment {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Song newSong = new Song();
       newSong.setTitle("Gimme Three Steps");
       newSong.setArtist("Lynyrd Skynyrd");
       newSong.setLength(157);
       
       newSong.display();
       
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your teacher likely wants to see you coding for the math, as seen in [correct Answer by idl99](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66219161/642706). But, FYI, you would not do so in real work.

## `Duration`

Java has a built-in type for a span-of-time unattached to the timeline: [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html).

```
Duration.ofSeconds( 157 )
```

You should be using this type as the member field on your class, rather than a mere `int`.

```java
public class Song
{ 
    // instance variable declaration 
   private String songTitle;
   private String songArtist;
   private Duration songLength;
…
```

Add constructors for handling either total number of seconds or a `Duration`.

```java
   // Constructors

   public Song (String title , String artist , int min , int sec )
   {
        this( title , artist , Duration.ofMinutes( min ).plusSeconds( sec ) ) ;
   }

   public Song (String title , String artist , int totalSeconds )
   {
       this( title , artist , Duration.ofSeconds( totalSeconds ) ) ;
   }

   public Song (String title , String artist , Duration duration )
   {
       this.songTitle = title; 
       this.songArtist = artist;
       this.songLength = duration ;
   }
```

> a song of 157 secs should be listed as 2:37

The standard textual representation of a duration is defined by [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations): `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS` where the `P` marks the beginning and the `T` separates any years-months-days from any hours-minutes-seconds. So your two minutes and thirty-seven minutes is `PT2M37S`.

I recommend using the standard format for clarity. Presenting a span of time as a clock-time such as `2:37` in inherently ambiguous and prone to confusion. But if you insist, built such a string using the `to…Part` methods.

```java
String output = duration.toMinutesPart() + ":" + duration.toSecondsPart() ;
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you could simply take the songLength in seconds in your constructor. So your overloaded constructor could be like,

```
public Song (String title,String artist, int sec ){
   this.songTitle = title; 
   this.songArtist = artist;
   this.songLength = sec;
}
```

Thereafter, you may convert the time in seconds to minutes and display the formatted song length as follows,

```
public void display( ){
   int minutes = getLength() / 60;
   
   // use modulo arithmetic operator "%" to get the remainder after dividing 157 seconds by 60
   // thereby you get the number of seconds elapsed in the last minute which is 37 seconds in the 3rd minute according to your example
   int seconds = getLength() % 60;
   
   // this is the way to print a formatted string
   // it will print like "Title by Artist [2:37]"
   System.out.printf("%s by %s [%d:%d]", getTitle(), getArtist(), minutes, seconds);
}
```

Hope this helps you :) If it did, I would very much appreciate it if you marked my answer as "Accepted". Good day to you!